# Can a computer with Kaby Lake processor run Windows 7 in a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, central-processing-unit, windows-10

My boss bought computers with Kaby Lake processors for a project. Only later did we find out that the project requires components that will not work with Windows 10 (and do work with Windows 7) and their developer is unlikely to release new components compatible with Windows 10. We are looking at various options and want to know whether this (running Windows 7 in a virtual machine) is feasible.

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to run Windows 7 in any virtualization environment (Virtual box or Vmware workstation. Make sure that you have enabled Intel VT from BIOS. It is necessary to run 64 bit guest OS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it works without problem, except updates are not possible.
But since it is a VM you move your VM, open it with another computer with older CPU and do the updates. I have my VM on external SSD Samsung T3.
Besides I think in the most cases you don't need the updates.